# How do I do a wildcard tag search?

Tags: support, search

The vba tag has several close neighbors such as vba-access, vba-excel etc. So I tried to search on any tag starting with vba by searching on [vba*], but reasons unclear search turned it into: [vba] or [vbaccelerator]

Is this not supported, or am I just doing it wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong side. [*vba]  for [access-vba]

Comment: I fail at life.

Comment: So tag's wildcard do exist :)